# Natural Earth: How to get the position of all provinces that belong to a state

Tags: shapefile, geojson

This question is about [Natural earth 1:10 states and provinces.shp](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-1-states-provinces) file. I'm using ogr2ogr and want to know the name of the id i need to pass . In purpose of pulling out the right states regions to make a geojson file with it. I've use couple of properties name that didn't work (-where "adm0_a3 IN ('MLI')" \ , -where "iso_a2 = 'ML'" \ ).
I get those id from [Let's make an map](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) tutorial but they where referring to another shape file. Can anyone help me .

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `-sql` variants, but I find the interface a bit oblique. In your shoes, I'd import the shapefile into a [PostGIS](http://www.PostGIS.org) table and then work from there. You get reliable querying and native support for GeoJSON export via [ST_AsGeoJSON](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_AsGeoJSON.html).